# How to implement UICollectionViewCells showing "stateful" contents?

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently refactoring my Newsstand app.

Previously, I was showing several custom `UIView`s ("CoverView") in a self-calculated grid layout (3 items per row, as many rows as necessary) embedded in a scroll view, scrolling vertically.

Each "CoverView" consists of

- a label (showing the issue title)
- an image (showing the issue cover)
- a button (showing "DOWNLOAD" or - if already downloaded - "READ")
- a progress bar (initially hidden, showing the download progress)

Each CoverView has it's own `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

If a user taps once, the button is hidden, the download progress bar is shown and constantly updated with the download progress:

```
 [issue addObserver:cover forKeyPath:@"downloadProgress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

(The long press recognizer is used to let the user delete the issue).

All CoverViews are stored in a NSMutableDictionary, and are always kept in memory. Although the unscaled images are rather big (1024 pixels high), I never had performance problems while scrolling, probably since there are not that many issues (and therefore CoverViews) to store.

Since the self-implemented grid-layout is complex and difficult to maintain, I wanted to use a `UICollectionView` instead. I added a collection view and made my CoverView class inherit from `UICollectionViewCell` (instead of `UIView`).

The display and scrolling works, but I'm having these problems:

1. The scrolling is lagging when a new row of cells needs to be shown and **collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** is called for each.
2. I tried to not reuse cells (to improve performance, strangely enough), but this failed due to each cell having to have it's *reuse identifier* set (and the "reuseIdentifier" property is readonly, so I cannot set it in code).
3. I don't know where to unset the observers for KVO for a cell. Is there a way to be notified once a cell gets queued for reuse?

In general, I'm unsure whether I'm misusing `UICollectionView` with my specific use case here and should stick to my previous approach, or whether it's just my inability to efficiently use and tweak `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I hope this code helpful for you: https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithProgressBar

Comment: Sang, thanks - the download is actually handled in the "Issue" class (which acts as Model and has no GUI-elements or -dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set 'reuseIdentifier', the proper design is to use UICollectionView methods :

- `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`
- or `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`

You typically call these methods once, depending on how you want to provide your cell's instantiation (inflated from NIB, or instantiated through standard `[[ViewClass alloc] init]`

Once views are registered, you can use them from UiCollectionView like this :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"yourReuseId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Collection view handle ALL the work :
    // 1 - retrieves a reusable view if views have already been recycled
    // or 2- instantiate a new one, using the class/nib you registered
    // So, cell SHOULDN'T be nil from here :)


    // Note : from iOS 6, UITableView has a similar auto-instantiation mechanism

}
```

3 - to unset KVO, override `UICollectionViewCell`'s `-(void)prepareForReuse` method (inherited from `UICollectionReusableView`)